# Smooth Streaming Player for Multiple Smooth Streaming Media Elements

Tags: c#, silverlight, streaming, smooth-streaming-player

Does current version of Silverlight Media Framework provides streaming with multiple smooth streaming media elements? For example, I would like to have a player that could play for a screen capture and another one for human just like this example  [Microsoft PDC](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/PDC/PDC10/CS03) . Is it possible to do with SMF? 
Are there any solutions/examples available which allow me to simultaneously stream multiple videos in on player?

Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a multi-cam demo sample in the IIS showcase, which is similar to the effect you are looking for...

[IIS Showcase Demos](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/iis-smooth-streaming/demo)

However, I must say I have not actually seen anyone use this yet, nor any code samples in how to achieve it.

It's worth noting, though - that in the case of Microsoft PDC, what you are watching is, in fact, a single stream. The camera and screen capture sources are simply combined into that layout pre-encoding (via either a video switcher or perhaps a software encoder like Wirecast). It requires a little more work on the "production" side, but makes your deployment a lot easier, and you don't need 2x the encoding power.